# Removing isolated points to get a perfect set

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces

The motivating question is the following: If $F$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^1$, can one find a perfect set $E\subset F$ such that $m(E)=m(F)$ (in Lebesgue measure)?

Define $F_0=F$ and $F_n=\{\text{accumulation points of }F_{n-1}\}$ for every $n\ge1$. Take $E=\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty F_n$. Each $F_n$ has only <strike>finitely</strike> countably many isolated points, hence $m(F_n)=m(F_{n-1})$. Thus $m(E)=\lim m(F_n)=m(F)$. Also note that each $F_n$ is closed, hence so is $E$. The problem is to prove that $E$ is perfect.

To summarize:

> Let $F_0$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^1$. Define $F_n=\{\text{accumulation points of }F_{n-1}\}$ for every $n\ge1$, and $E=\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty F_n$. Is $E$ necessarily perfect?

Comment: As far as I remember - and I may well be misremembering - $E$ isn't necessarily perfect, you have to repeat it until the first uncountable ordinal. ($F_0 = F$; for a successor ordinal $F_{\alpha+1} = \{ \text{accumulation points of } F_\alpha\}$, and for limit ordinals $F_\alpha = \bigcap\limits_{\beta < \alpha} F_\beta$. $F_{\omega_1}$ is perfect - but I don't see how to directly prove it has the same Lebesgue measure.)

Comment: The result you want to look at is the Cantor-Bendixson theorem, which is much stronger than you need for your motivating question (because the set of points in $F$ that are not in $E$ is countable). Indeed, you can find a perfect set $E \subseteq F$ such that $E$ is perfect, $m(E) = m(F),$ and every open interval either has empty intersection with $E$ or a positive measure intersection with $E.$ (If $m(F) = 0,$ then $E$ winds up being the empty set, so this stronger version is mainly of interest when $m(F) > 0.)$

Comment: But, you can get a perfect set in one step by letting $E = \{\text{condensation points of } F\}$.

Comment: To elaborate on my earlier comment, the point behind the stronger version I described can be understood when you realize that perfect sets have the property that each open interval has either an empty intersection with the perfect set or a cardinality continuum intersection with the perfect set. Thus, "cardinality continuum intersection" gets strengthened to "positive measure intersection".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things. First, each $F_n$ has only countably many isolated points, for example $\mathbb Z$ has only (and more than finitely many) isolated points, on the other hand, there is a neighbourhood of an isolated point which does not contain any other point of $F_n$, as uncountably many open sets in $\mathbb R$ cannot be pairwise disjoint, we can have only countably many.

Second, in general $E := F_\omega = \bigcap_{n <\omega} F_n$ will not be perfect, start with $0$, add a sequence converging to $0$, add a sequence converging to one of the added points, continue this $\omega$ often to obtain $F$. Then $E = \{0\}$. What you can do is continue after the $\omega$th step.That is for $\alpha < \omega_1$ define by induction $$ F_{\alpha + 1} = \{\text{accumulation points of $F_{\alpha}$}\},\quad F_{\lambda} = \bigcap_{\beta < \lambda} F_\beta \text{ for limit ordinals $\lambda$} $$
Then $(F_\alpha)_{\alpha < \omega_1}$ is a dreasing sequence of closed sets. As such a sequence can only be of countable length, before being constant, there is an $\alpha^* < \omega_1$ such that $F_{\alpha^*} = F_{\alpha^*+1}$, hence $F_{\alpha^*}$ is perfect. Now, as before, is the usual step, we have $m(F_{\alpha + 1}) = m(F_\alpha)$ for $\alpha < \omega_1$, as only coubntably many points are removed, and continuity of the measure gives 
$$ m(F_\lambda) = \inf_{\alpha < \lambda} m(F_\alpha) = m(F_0) $$
in the limit steps, so $m(F_{\alpha^*}) = m(F_0)$ and $F_{\alpha^*}$ is perfect.